# vuejs - how to add array to the target data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to add data like this

category1

- company1
- company2
- company3

category2

- company1
- company2
- company3

my code

```js
getlist() {
      var list = this.lists;
      var category
    //   var company 
      this.$http.get("/getlist")
      .then((res) => {
          var obj = res.data;
          for(var [key] in obj) {
              var company =[];
            for(var i in obj[key].company) {
                company.push( obj[key].company[i].name)
            }
              console.log(company);
              list.push({
                  "category_name" : obj[key].name,
                  "companies": [
                      {name: company}
                      ]
              })
              list.category_name = '',
              list.companies = '',
              company= ''
          }
      })
  },
```

list form is look like this

```js
         {
                category_name: 'Category1',
                companies: [
                    {name: 'company1'},
                ]
            },
```

and data is look like this

```js
[
    {
        "name": "Category2",
        "company": [
            {
                "name": "company1"
            }
            {
                "name": "company2"
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "name": "Category2",
        "company": [
            {
                "name": "company1"
            }
            {
                "name": "company2"
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

I don't know how to use forloop in this case.

Can it use double `for loop` in `list.push()`?

It is very tired for me..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you just want to rename the keys of data objects you retrieve from the server.

This should do it:

```
getlist() {
  this.$http.get('/getlist')
    .then(res => {
      let list = [];
      for (let item of res.data) {
        let newItem = {
          category_name: item.name,
          companies: item.company
        }
        list.push(newItem);
      }
      this.lists = list;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error retrieving "/getlist":', err)
    });
}
```